# Questions about differentiability

Tags: calculus

Which of these following statements is true?

a. Let $f:\mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb {R}^k$ and $g:\mathbb {R}^k \to \mathbb {R}^m$. If $g\circ f$ is differentiable, then $g$ and $f$ are differentiable.

b. Let $f:\mathbb {R}^m \to \mathbb {R}^n$ with $df(p)=0$ for $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $f$ is in a neighbourhood $p$ constant.

c. Let $g:\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ be differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$. Then is $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$, $f(x,y) := g(x)$ differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

I'm pretty sure that a. is false but I'm not really sure about the rest. I think that b. is true and that c. is true, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, $a$ is false. Just build $f$ and $g$ such that $g\circ f = 0$.

However, $b$ is false as well : just take $m=n=1$, and $f(x) = x^3$. Unless what you meant was $\forall p, df(p) = 0$.

And finally, yes, $c$ is true. You can easily compute the differential of $f$ in terms of $g'$.

Answer (score 0):

The first two do not even hold on the line.

a) consider  $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=|x|$ then $g\circ f(x)=x^2$ is defferentiable but  g is not.

b) consider $f(x)= sinx$.